# Easy to use PNG lib?

Tags: c++, .net, png

Could someone recommend me a **simple, easy to use** PNG library either for c++ or .NET? All it needs to do is: load big PNG images (say 20000x20000), and tell me what color each pixel has.

Bitmap class in .NET can't load big images, throws an OutOfMemory exception.

I spent reasonable time on google looking through c++ libs, but all of them does much more than I need, and their usage is too complicated for me.

Comment: That is **very** big – about 400MB (so even after compression > 40MB). Where do you get such files from?

Comment: More like 1.2GB if it's in 24-bit colour. 1.6GB if it's 32 bits per pixel. So it may simply be that you are actually out of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The defacto standard library for PNG files is [LibPNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).  It's not the best designed API in the world, but if you just work through the steps in one of their tutorials, it's pretty hard to mess up.

You'll probably find it easiest to wrap their API in a few simple functions (or class) of your own.  Once you have that done, you should be good to go.

Comment: This would be my choice. For simple problems, it's a good choice.

Comment: The best one I have found is LodePng: https://lodev.org/lodepng/

Comment: The problem is the documentation is attrocious and the design is orientated around reading from files rather than pngs already in memory. The issue is the png_set_read_fn which is a nightmare to use as there's about 5 incomplete examples on the internet of how it works, and nobody can explain it properly with a full working example. It's horrendously confusing.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

http://nothings.org/stb_image.c

You can use it instead of zlib aswell.

Comment: This is by far easier to use than `libpng`.   For example, here's how to load a png, and display the width and height and channels ```int x, y, comp;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(argv[1], &x, &y, &comp, 1);
    fprintf(stdout, "width: %d, height: %d, comp: %d\n", x, y, comp);
    stbi_image_free(data); ```

Answer (score 2):

If C# is an option, try [PNGCS](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/). It was done (by myself, in Java originally) for this scenario, it allows you to read and write line by line, no need to have all data in memory.

I have tested that it can read and write huge files (30000 x 30000 pixels, more than 2GB in disk), [at least in Java](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/source/browse/pnjg/src/ar/com/hjg/pngj/test/CreateVeryHuge.java)

Answer (score 1):

For C++:

Depending on the license you are able to use you may have a look at:

DeVIL: http://openil.sourceforge.net/(a bit outdated but a still good choice) (Linux, Win)

ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php (well maintained, all platforms)

both support a variety of input and output formats.

EDIT: now also on Github: https://github.com/DentonW/DevIL

Comment: Also worth mentioning is GraphicsMagick (http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), a fork of ImageMagick.